# Add entry to beginning of list and remove the last one

Tags: python, list, append

I have a `list` of about 40 entries. And I frequently want to append an item to the start of the list (with id 0) and want to delete the `last` entry (with id 40) of the list.

How do I do this the best?

Example with 5 entries:

```
[0] = "herp"
[1] = "derp"
[2] = "blah"
[3] = "what"
[4] = "da..."
```

after adding `"wuggah"` and deleting last it should be like:

```
[0] = "wuggah"
[1] = "herp"
[2] = "derp"
[3] = "blah"
[4] = "what"
```

And I don't want to end up manually moving them one after another all of the entries to the next id.

Comment: "And I don't want to end up manually moving them one after another all of the entries to the next id."  Internally, a list object allocates a larger list than the size of the list that is currently used (10 elements, but list is actually a lot bigger than that). So behind the scene it is doing all that for you - this amortized the running time of insertion, pop at a particular position and other operates as low as possible. http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> import collections
>>> q = collections.deque(["herp", "derp", "blah", "what", "da.."])
>>> q.appendleft('wuggah')
>>> q.pop()
'da..'
>>> q
deque(['wuggah', 'herp', 'derp', 'blah', 'what'])
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this the same as `myList.insert(0, "wuggah")`?

Comment: @wagglewax Yes, except this is an O(1) operation instead of O(n).

Answer (score 13):

Use `insert()` to place an item at the beginning of the list:

```
myList.insert(0, "wuggah")
```

Use `pop()` to remove and return an item in the list. Pop with no arguments pops the last item in the list

```
myList.pop() #removes and returns "da..."
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```
In [21]: from collections import deque

In [22]: d = deque([], 3)   

In [24]: for c in '12345678':
   ....:     d.appendleft(c)
   ....:     print d
   ....:
deque(['1'], maxlen=3)
deque(['2', '1'], maxlen=3)
deque(['3', '2', '1'], maxlen=3)
deque(['4', '3', '2'], maxlen=3)
deque(['5', '4', '3'], maxlen=3)
deque(['6', '5', '4'], maxlen=3)
deque(['7', '6', '5'], maxlen=3)
deque(['8', '7', '6'], maxlen=3)
```

Comment: Using the max length is a better solution here, more elegant, that said, the OP wanted to prepend the item, not append it - you want ``deque.appendleft()``. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner, but it probably isn't as efficient as some of the others ...

```
myList=["wuggah"] + myList[:-1]
```

Also note that it creates a new list, which may not be what you want ...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
L = ["herp", "derp", "blah", "what", "da..."]

L[:0]= ["wuggah"]
L.pop()
```